# How do I *permanently* remove the "What's New" spam icon in Firefox 71?

Tags: firefox

I know about the ***browser.messaging-system.whatsNewPanel.enabled*** setting. I have it set to false. The icon keeps re-appearing after a random amount of time. Over, and over, and over...

The "Remove from toolbar" context menu item is disabled. It's actively hidden from the "Customize" UI.

There is no doubt whatsoever that this is done on purpose, and I've just about had it being harassed by Mozilla now.

Comment: What are you seeing?  I have Firefox V71.0 running in Ubuntu and I do not see any difference between this and   Firefox V68 in Kali.  I think I just saw it - it was a new tab that I had to close

Comment: Do you have any group policies applied that are reseting your profile?

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a bug in the new version. When I've searched for `whatsnew` in *about:config* and cleared *all* the values, or set them  to false, the obnoxious icon is gone for some time... and reappears.

[image: WhatsNew panel config]

**However**, the settings for `uitour` also appear to control this icon, and may be related to a [known bug](https://bedrock.readthedocs.io/en/latest/uitour.html). Setting enabled to `false` did not prevent the icon reappearance.

[image: Search for uitour]

BTW, if you prefer the traditional appearance of *about:config*, use the URL `chrome://global/content/config.xul`, which displays data by columns. One wonders why Mozilla hid that feature and added the UITour icon!